# Static Stop/Play Functions

Tags: actionscript-3, class, static, frame

Let's say I would want to use the frameScript method to add some stop and play methods to some frames.

Normally I would declare the stop function:

```
private function $FUN_FrameStop():void {
            stop();
            return;
        }
```

and then use it like this:

```
addFrameScript(47, $FUN_FrameStop, 122, $FUN_FrameStop);
```

**My question is, how can I create the same $FUN_FrameStop as a static function?**

Static functions do not allow the use of `this` since static members are bound to a class and are not inherited by that class' instances.

**So, is there a way to create a function similar to $FUN_FrameStop, but static?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there's no way unless I have a static reference to the class instance, but that's not what I want.

```
public static var staticClassRef:MovieClip;
function $FUN_FrameStop():void {
staticClassRef.stop();
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never added any frame script dynamically but.. did you try using the instance as the parameter?

```
    private static function $FrameStop($inst:MovieClip):void {
        $inst.stop();
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but the issue is that addFrameScript doesn't allow using functions with parameters. In my example, $FUN_FrameStop isn't actually called- like $FUN_FrameStop()

Comment: If the function must be static and cannot take any parameters, then there is no way to make it work following good oop principles.  The only way to get a reference to "this" to a static function without passing parameters would be to store the reference in a static location, and handle the case where it hasn't been set yet, but that's just ugly programming.

Answer (score -1):

You may declare a function outside of class but in package

```
package
{
    public function Func(): void
    {
         trace( "Func" );
    }
}
```

then you may call it everywhare with Func() after including the package ( if needed )

Comment: Sorry, but what does this have to do with what I've asked?

Comment: the functions defined like this are static. But if won to make a static function members of class you may define it with public static function in class definition.

Comment: ...You're missing the point here. I'm not asking for general advice, I need a specific answer to my question. (Check inhan's answer for example, which doesn't solve the issue but is relevant to what I've asked).

Comment: First of all you use undocumented function this is not a good idea, second you want to use stop() function wich is a method of the movie clip so you must pass its refernce to a function like inhan says, but you cannot do this using addFrameScript. I wish you luck.

Comment: I know it's undocumented, but I need to use it. If I use a class before it gets to implement the frame scripts, then the frame scripts are completely ignored.